# Convolutions with changes to the argument

Tags: convolution

I think I understand what happens when I shift the argument, but I'm not sure what should happen when the signal is compressed or expanded. In particular I'm trying to figure out what happens when the convolution where $y(t)=x(t)*h(t)$ is changed to $x(t/k)*h(t/k)$ or $x(t/k)*h(t)$. Supposedly the first should be $y(kt)/k$ and the second should be unable to be done but I don't know how to get there. When I work the first one out, I get $\int{x(\frac{\tau}{k})h(\frac{t-\tau}{k})}$. This doesn't look like something I can get by changing the argument of $y$, so I must be missing something. Any help on how to go about doing these convolutions with arguments other than t would be helpful.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "This doesn't look like something I can get by changing the argument of y, so I must be missing something"? Because it does look okay to me...

Comment: It would be very helpful to you if you avoided shortcuts _such as ignoring limits on integral signs and skipping writing the $\mathrm d\tau$ or something similar at the end of the integrand_ and reading up a bit on _change of variable_ in integrals. You might also consider if $k$ is intended to be an integer or can be any real number, and whether $k$ is restricted to being positive; the answer might be somewhat different,,,,

Comment: Sorry I mean that I don't see why changing the argument of y and dividing by k is the same as changing the arguments of both signals being convolved. Since y(t) equals that integral, shouldn't what I do to it only affect the second signal in the integral? I don't understand how y(t/k)k=x(t/k)∗h(t/k) and I don't understand exactly why I can't do the second convolution. You're right, I apologize for leaving things out, and I believe k can be any real number since this is a continuous time signal not discrete time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me show you how to manipulate the convolution integral.

Let

$$y(t)  = x(t) \star h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau) h(t-\tau) d\tau \tag{1} $$

Let $a > 1$ that we have a *compressed* signal $y(at)$ ;

$$y(at)  = \int_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau) h(at-\tau) d\tau \tag{2} $$

Substitude $\tau' = \tau/a$ so that $\tau = a \tau'$ and $d\tau = a \cdot d\tau'$ into Eq.2 :

\begin{align}
y(at)  &= \int_{\tau'=-\infty}^{\infty} x(a \tau')~ h(at-a\tau') ~a ~d\tau' \tag{3}\\ \\
&= a \int_{\tau'=-\infty}^{\infty} x(a \tau') ~ h(a(t-\tau')) ~d\tau' \tag{4}\\ \\
&= a \int_{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty} x(a \tau) ~ h(a(t-\tau)) ~d\tau  = a \cdot \big( x(at) \star h(at) \big) \tag{5}
\end{align}

Eq.5 shows that the compressed output $y(at)$ is obtained by the convolution of the compressed input $x(at)$ and the compressed impulse response $h(at)$, and (also the result scaled by $a$)....

Note that *convolution* operator assumes an LTI (linear time-invariant) framework. However, the *compressor* is not an LTI system and it does not have an impulse response $h_c(t)$, so that $y(at) = y(t) \star h_c(t)$ can not be true.

Assume for a moment that the compressor is an LTI system with impulse response $h_c(t)$. Then we can consider the generation of the compressed output in two (serial) LTI stages:

$$ x(t) \longrightarrow \boxed{ h(t) } \longrightarrow \boxed{ h_c(t)} \longrightarrow y(at) \tag{6}$$

From LTI theory we know that the cascade of two LTI blocks is also LTI with an equivalent impulse response given by $h_e(t) = h(t) \star h_c(t)$ hence Eq.6 can be written as :

$$ y(at) = x(t) \star h_e(t)  = x(t) \star ( h(t) \star h_c(t)) = x(t) \star h(at)\tag{7}$$

Which is contradicting the result we have obtained in Eq.5, hence the assumption that the compressor could have been represented with an impulse reponse was wrong.

Another implication of this is also observed in the *time-reversal* of the output $y(t)$ :
$$y(-t) = x(-t) \star h(-t) \neq x(-t) \star h(t) \neq x(t) \star h(-t) $$

The reason of the unequal signs is again about *reversal* operation not being an LTI system.

On the other hand, if you want to apply an LTI operation on the output such as $y_d(t) = y(t-d)$ , then it can be simply be reflected in the convolution as:

$$ y(t-d) = y(t) \star \delta(t-d) = (x(t) \star h(t)) \star \delta(t-d) = x(t) \star h(t-d)$$...

Comment: This answer is above and beyond and really helped me. I thought it would be a process similar to that but I did part of it wrong. So thanks, I appreciate your time!

Comment: @KanedaSlide Glad if I could help, putting detailed answers is not always recommended ;-)

Comment: For completeness, perhaps you can tell us what happens when $a < 0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Actually I've also provided a *hint* by showing the case for $a = -1$  as $y(-t) = x(-t) \star h(-t)$, so the reader can generalize it for arbitrary $a <-1$  ;-)

Comment: Errr, no. Your comments about the case $a=-1$ are in the part about different scaling in the two "arguments" and you pull the equalityy $$y(-t)=x(-t)\star h(-t)$$ out of a hat with no justification whatsoever; the claim about time reversal not corresponding to an LTI system has nothing to do with this _equality_.  What _really_ should have been said was that if $y(t) = x(t)\star h(t)$, then for $a\neq 0$, $$x(at)\star h(at)= |a^{-1}|y(at)$$ the proof should have pointed why the absolute value sign is needed (for $a<0$, the integral limits reverse and so the $a$ you pulled out becomes $-a=|a|$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate To show what happens for $a<-1$ Let $$a = -1 \cdot |a| \tag{0}$$ In the answer I've shown that for a positive number, such as $|a|$, we have $$y(|a|t)=|a|x(|a|t)\star h(|a|t) \tag{1}$$Now, it's given that $$y(-t)=x(-t)\star h(-t) \tag{2}$$ Then combining Eqs 1&2, we see that $$y(-|a|t)=|a|x(-|a|t)\star h(-|a|t) \tag{3}$$ But Eq.0 says $-|a| = a$, then for all $a$ with $|a|>1$ we have : $$y(at)=|a|x(at)\star h(at) \tag{4}$$ I believe this was indicated by the answer. I have just stated the case for $a=-1$ without a proof, but it's a given. So the reader should be able to do it.